# Does Microsoft Active Directory have an option to be an identity provider?

Tags: active-directory, single-sign-on

I’m looking to integrate with a SSO IdP (identity provider) and trying to understand whether AD can serve that role. 
I.e., I set up users on AD, users authenticate on a webpage that checks the validity of their password with AD which generates a signed token I can use to log into my app.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, AD can be easily used as an Identity Provider for Single Sign on purpose.

If you're going for it, achieving Web single sign on (SSO) through Microsoft's **AD FS (Active Directory Federation Services)** would be a good choice.

I'll quote the overview from [MSDN Article on Active Directory Federation Services](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb897402.aspx):

> **Overview**
>
> AD FS is a standards-based service that allows the secure sharing of
> identity information between trusted business partners (known as a
> federation) across an extranet. When a user needs to access a Web
> application from one of its federation partners, the user's own
> organization is responsible for authenticating the user and providing
> identity information in the form of "claims" to the partner that hosts
> the Web application. The hosting partner uses its trust policy to map
> the incoming claims to claims that are understood by its Web
> application, which uses the claims to make authorization decisions.
>
> AD FS is Microsoft's implementation of the WS-Federation Passive
> Requestor Profile protocol (passive indicates that the client
> requirements are just a cookie- and JavaScript-enabled Web browser).
> AD FS implements the standards based WS-Federation protocol and
> Security Assertion Markup Language (SAML).
>
> ...  // follow the link shared above for more information.